# audio auto play next song when previous is finished

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I want to create an audio background player where user can only click on image to play or stop the playback. I have trouble creating or rewirting existing codes to make a playlist for it, that automatically plays next song when previous is finished. I want to do it in vanilla js.

 Here is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/rockarou/ad8Lkkrj/

```
var imageTracker = 'playImage';

swapImage = function() {
  var image = document.getElementById('swapImage');
  if (imageTracker == 'playImage') {
    image.src = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/129/soft_scraps/256/button_pause_01.png';
    imageTracker = 'stopImage';
  } else {
    image.src = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/129/soft_scraps/256/button_play_01.png';
    imageTracker = 'playImage';
  }
};

var musicTracker = 'noMusic';

audioStatus = function() {
  var music = document.getElementById('natureSounds');
  if (musicTracker == 'noMusic') {
    music.play();
    musicTracker = 'playMusic';
  } else {
    music.pause();
    musicTracker = 'noMusic';
  }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is the trick to trigger next song:

```
music.addEventListener('ended',function(){
      //play next song
    });
```

How to play another song on same audio tag:

```
 music.pause();
 music.src = "new url";
 music.load();
 music.play();
```

Now here is a cool example of a playlist in html5, you can load each song at the time, case some clients (mobile) will not be happy when you consume the traffic, in next example all audios are loaded at same time to have a smooth transition from song to song,
loading the songs:

```
//playing flag 
var musicTracker = 'noMusic';
//playlist audios
var audios = [];
 $(".song").each(function(){
        var load = new  Audio($(this).attr("url"));
    load.load();
    load.addEventListener('ended',function(){
       forward();
    });
    audios.push(load);
 });
//active track
var activeTrack = 0;
```

Highlighting witch song is playing, with a bit of jquery, yeah, case yeah I'm lazy, lazy:

```
var showPlaying = function()
{
    var src = audios[activeTrack].src;
   $(".song").removeClass("playing");
   $("div[url='" + src + "']").addClass("playing");
};
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zm5ugnk4/3/)

Note: If the sound's doesn't play, manually check if audio url's are accessible

Comment: I want it to be in javascript not jquery

Answer (score 6):

[Here a non vanilla solution.] My playlist consists of four songs, they are named 0.mp3, 1.mp3, 2.mp3 and 3.mp3.

```
<html>  
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>       
<audio id="player" autoplay controls><source src="0.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
</body>
<script>
    var x = 0;
    var music = document.getElementById("player");
    $("#player").bind("ended", function(){
    x=x+1;
    music.src = x%4 + ".mp3";
    music.load();
    music.play();       
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

The playlist is repeated indefinetely.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Javascript variant:

```js
  const audioArray = document.getElementsByClassName('songs'); //Get a list of all songs
  let i = 0; //Initiate current Index

  const player = document.getElementById('player'); //get the player
  player.src = audioArray[i].getAttribute('data-url'); //set first Song to play
  player.addEventListener('ended',function(){ //when a song finished playing
    i++; //increase index
    if (i < audioArray.length) { //If current index is smaller than count of songs
      player.src = audioArray[i].getAttribute('data-url'); //set next song
      return; // stop further processing of this function for now
    }
    // current index is greater than count of songs
    i = 0; // therefore we reset the current index to the first available song
    player.src = audioArray[i].getAttribute('data-url'); // and set it to be played
  });
```

In this example you don't set an initial src for the audioplayers source-tag but instead have a list of class 'song'-items with an data-url attribute containing the url/path to the tracks.

I added comments to learn what and why this code is doing what it does.
Of course it could be better but it's a quick throwup of code ;)